# Почему пишут "библиотека STL", но используют пространство имен "std"?

Tags: c++, stl, терминология

Везде пишут: `Использования STL функций...`, но в коде мы вызываем **std**::func(), а не **stl**::func(). 
Вопрос: что это такое и как это понять? Возможно кто-то сможет провести аналогию с пакетами с Java.
Почему пишет `STL`, а используем `std`?

Comment: STL функциями называют коротко. Имеется ввиду функции из стандартной библиотеки

Comment: stl -- это `standart template library` -- часть стандартной библиотеки

Comment: В дополнение к ответу ниже, [на англоSO про это подробно рассказали](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827236/what-is-the-stl).

Comment: [Немного истории создания STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library#History) (к сожалению, на английском). Кстати, говорят, что впоследствии Степанов разочаровался в самом объектном подходе, реализованном в С++

Comment: А ещё можно просто прочитать описание метки [stl](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/stl/info).

Comment: @avp как я понимаю из  слова `template` можно сделать вывод, что это только набор прототипов, а их реализация лежит уже где-то в другом месте?

Comment: @DimaKhodan, ну, по месту реализовано тоже немало (можете полюбопытствовать в /usr/include/c++/*/bits/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Название STL было поначалу, означало отдельную, не входящую в тогдашний стандарт библиотеку. Сейчас это просто часть стандартной библиотеки С++.

Пространства имен `stl` никогда не было, есть пространство имен `std`, в котором находятся функции стандартной библиотеки C++.

Примерно так. В общем, название STL не имеет никакой связи с пространством имен, каковым является `std`.

Comment: получаеться, что это вроде как java.lang? 
то есть когда мы говорим о STL, на самом деле имеются ввиду функцию с пространства имен std? 
выходит, что <iostream>, <vector> и тд, это аналог разных подпакетов в одном пакете  в Java?

Comment: Я делаю библиотеку под названием **Супер-Пупер библиотека**, и помещаю ее функции в пространство имен `HarryLib`. Или я обязан давать имя, совпадающее с названием библиотеки? :) Ну нет в С++ (пока что?) модулей. И говорить " когда мы говорим о STL, на самом деле имеются ввиду функцию с пространства имен std" - тоже неверно. Ну не связаны между собой эти понятия... Ну так назвали в свое время библиотеку. Ну вот назову я вашу java.lang - "Системная библиотека Java" - так что, теперь к ее функциям обращаться как `Системная библиотека Java.func()`?...